# White space on right side of website in Mobile devices

Tags: css, layout

I have an issue with website on mobile devices view...
To be much worse, on every mobile device, site is displaying exactly as in desktop view (this is the part which i need ),but problem is i can't debbug and find css error. The problem is white space on right side of website, and its visible in slider part-slider is not full screen width, as whole website too.
you can see white vertical space in screnshots here [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZIGB.jpg)
Website is [Site link](https://techmonegy.com/), and here are screenshots of my problem

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem

```
<header id="header-v5" class="header clearfix" style="width:100px">
<div class="wrapper header-v5-wrapper clearfix">
<div class="sixteen spans">
<div class="logo" i="">
<div class="slogan">
</div>
</div>
```

the header part is not responsive, for example the `class="sixteen spans"` has a `width:960px` while being previewed as a 320x480

Comment: its the same princip as you did your body, just in this case go with your header classes

Comment: gimme your @media css so i can add you the classes :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cg2hYm6m
Thank you in advance... I am not so familiar with mobile design....

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.wrapper .sixteen.spans {
    width: 100%;
}
.one_fourth {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.one_fourth {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
#copyright .wrapper { width: 100%;}`

This is working for me, in case you get stuck, add `!important` to the copyright ( footer ) to override the other width.

a little tip, if you are doing responsive, rather use % then pixel

Comment: Hmm...nothing happened ..Can you see white space in right side from pictures on mobile devices...It's again here ..It is the biggest problem ?

Comment: the whitespace is apearing becase some element is wider then the given screen, i pointed out everything thats on it , so inspect element and scan the few elements ;)